# oc.lazyload not working with ui-router, js loaded but controller not initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I'm trying to use ui-router with lazyload, from chrome I can see the required js is loaded but angular throws an error.

From the error I can tell the controller is not initialised, attached the router code:

```
var app = angular.module('aaaaa', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/pages/dashboard');

  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/pages/:name',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
      return 'templates/' + $stateParams.name + '.html';
    },
    controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
      return $stateParams.name;
    },
    resolve: {
      loader: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$stateParams', function($ocLazyLoad, $stateParams) {
        var url = 'templates/controllers/' + $stateParams.name + '.js';
        console.log(url);

        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
          name: 'aaaaa',
          files: [url]
        });
      }]
    }
  });
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor your `resolve.loader` function as such:

```
loader: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$stateParams', function($ocLazyLoad, $stateParams) {
  var url = 'templates/controllers/' + $stateParams.name + '.js';

  return $ocLazyLoad.load(url).then(function () {
    return $stateParams.name;
  });
}]
```

Now, when ocLazyLoad has successfully loaded your controller code, we return the *name* of your controller (I'm assuming it's actual name matches that of `$stateParams.name`, as that is how you are referring to it in the controllerProvider).

And then in the `controllerProvider`:

```
controllerProvider: function (loader) {
  return loader;
}
```

`controllerProvider` nowadays accept the resolved values, not just stateParams - as per the following commit: [ui-router#851f8e46](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/851f8e469ba86e497b54048d66b9e49bceea7f30).

This was introduced in `0.2.14` and has since been [changed again](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/afa20f22373b7176b26daa7e1099750c4254a354), it now has support for `resolved` values in the `templateUrl` function aswell.

> *So as an aside, you could pass `loaded` into your templateUrl function as opposed to `$stateParams.name if you upgrade to 0.2.15. One value to rule 'em all?*

---

For the heck of it, I would put a `debugger` statement at the top of your `controllerProvider` function beforehand to inspect the `$stateParams.name` and ensure it is the same as that of `$stateParams.name` inside the `resolve.loader` function. *For the heck of it.*

---

Also, it could prove *very* helpful to see the error thrown, the dev console output as well as the implementation details of your controller / module.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

In the separate controller file, you can't write this,

```
app.controller ('xxx', [ ... ]);
```

Instead, use

```
angular.module('xxxx').controller ('xxx', [ ... ])
```

I don't know why yet, but it worked.